# want one more input if someone select USA using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want one more input if someone select USA using jquery , please help i do not have enough knowledge about jquery

my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>jQuery Select Change Event For Dependent Select Option Field - Demo Preview</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

<!-- include css file here-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="select_jquery.css"/>

<!-- include JavaScript file here-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select_jquery.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">

<div class="main">
   <h2>Dependent Select Option Field Example</h2><hr/></br>

<label>Select Country:</label><br/><br/>

<div id="prm">

<select id="country">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
    <option>FRANCE</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<label>Select City:</label><br/><br/>

<select id="city">
<!--Dependent Select option field-->
</select>

</div>
</div>

<!-- Div Fugo is advertisement div-->
<div class="fugo">
 <a href="http://www.formget.com/app/"><img src="images/formget.jpg" /></a>
</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Initializing arrays with city names
var USA = [
    {display: "Washington, D.C.", value: "WashingtonDC" }, 
    {display: "Alaska", value: "Alaska" }, 
    {display: "New York", value: "New-York" },
    {display: "Florida", value: "Florida" },
    {display: "Hawaii", value: "Hawaii" },
    {display: "California", value: "California" }];

var AUSTRALIA = [
    {display: "Canberra", value: "Canberra" }, 
    {display: "Sydney", value: "Sydney" }, 
    {display: "Melbourne", value: "Melbourne" },
    {display: "Perth", value: "Perth" },
    {display: "Gold Coast ", value: "Gold-Coast" }];

var FRANCE = [
    {display: "Paris", value: "Paris" }, 
    {display: "Avignon", value: "Avignon" }, 
    {display: "Strasbourg", value: "Strasbourg" },
    {display: "Nice", value: "Nice" }];

//Function executes on change of first select option field 
$("#country").change(function(){

var select = $("#country option:selected").val();

switch(select){
case "USA":
    city(USA);
break;

case "AUSTRALIA":
    city(AUSTRALIA);
break;

case "FRANCE":
    city(FRANCE);
break;

default:
    $("#city").empty();
    $("#city").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
break;
}
});

//Function To List out Cities in Second Select tags
function city(arr){
    $("#city").empty();//To reset cities
    $("#city").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
    $(arr).each(function(i){//to list cities
        $("#city").append("<option value=\""+arr[i].value+"\">"+arr[i].display+"</option>")
    });
}

});
```

i want one more input if someone select USA using jquery , please help i do not have enough knowledge about jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple approch is to write the input in your html code and let it hidden with `display:none` and oce the user check the USA option you show it here is how you will process

```
<select id="country">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>AUSTRALIA</option>
    <option>FRANCE</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="test" class="added" required style="display:none">
```

and in your JS file you can simply add this line to your code

```
switch(select){
case "USA":
    city(USA);
    $(".added").show();

break;
```